# OpenServer / php и exec() shell_exec() system()

Tags: php, openserver

Подскажите как на OpenServer (Windows 10) запустить `exec()` или аналоги с nohup. Что бы php не ожидал завершение процесса

```
> NUL 2> NUL
```

не помогает, он просто уничтожает вывод, а с nohup и вовсе не работает.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил этой функции в статье

Answer (score 0):

Так `$cmd` выполнится в фоновом режиме, не дожидаясь, пока PHP закончит работу, как на Windows, так и на Unix:

```
<?php
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}
?>
```