# запуск bat файла в apache windows 7

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, bat

имею локальный apache server. как из php скрипта запустить bat файл лежащий со скриптом в одной папке?
пробовал так:

```
exec("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe openfolder.bat");//файл лежал в одной папке с php скриптом  
exec('"D:/openfolder.bat"');
exec("D:/openfolder.bat");  
exec("openfolder.bat");//тут тоже
exec("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe D:/openfolder.bat");  

system('"C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe openfolder.bat"');
system('"D:/openfolder.bat"');
system("D:/openfolder.bat");  
system("openfolder.bat");
system("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe D:/openfolder.bat");
```

в скрипте команда

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "D:\server\www\image"
```

Для D:\openfolder.bat поставил все права для всех юзеров. 
Ни один вариант не сработал. Запуск самого файла из системы работает и открывает папку

Comment: `exec()` и подобное

Comment: страница зависает

Comment: тогда опишите задачу более детально. например, нужно вам ожидать завершения выполнения бат-файла или нет. и т.п.

Comment: дополнил вопрос. завершения не ожидаю

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723555/223826